# Files in IsolatedStorage keep getting deleted. Is that expected?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I’m storing user state in an xml file in IsolatedStorage.  When I run my app in the emulator I notice that these files often disappear.  Everything works fine when the app is running – it seems to be when the app restarts (it happens when if keep the emulator open or not).

Is Windows deleting my files in IsolatedStorage to save space?  Should expect this behavior on the actual device or is this just an emulator bug?

Thanks,

Comment: If the phone wipes out storage on every restart, they don't need to provide tools to add/remove/browse/manage storage.  if they don't need to provide those tools, they can work on other things instead.

Comment: Offtopic: You can also consider, saving the user-state data in the State property of the PhoneApplicationService class. FYI --> http://bit.ly/avgEzL

Comment: Had no idea about this application state.  That's exactly what I need.  Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isolated Storage being deleted is normal, if you close the emulator completely. If it's being deleted on start (without the emulator closing), it sounds like your code is causing the file to either be deleted or overwritten. Could you post your code of any IsolatedStorage activity during the startup of your application?

Comment: OK interesting.  My app doesn't call any deletes so not sure how useful my code would be.  So are you saying that it is expected that files are deleted when the emulator restarts?  I'm assuming that this wil NOT be the case for a real device right?

Comment: just the emulator.  the real phone will not wipe isolated storage on restarts.

Answer (score 2):

Isolated Storage will also be wiped if you do a rebuild of your solution in Visual Studio. Rebuild triggers reinstall and install which wipes on the app's isolated storage.